Spring cloud Stream Kafka: Bootstrap broker disconnected
I am using String cloud stream kafka to send and receive messages.
Hear is my configuration:
spring:  
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: kafkaConsumer;kafkaProducer
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          replicationFactor: 1
          auto-create-topics: true
          brokers: 10.0.100.10:9092
      bindings:
        binding-import-device:
          destination: import-device-topic
          content-type: text/plain
          group: device

Hear is my KafkaConsumer, and KafkaProducer (I am using Jhipster to generate my project, this code is generated by Jhipster)
@Component
public class KafkaProducer implements Supplier<String> {

    @Override
    public String get() {
        return "kakfa_producer";
    }
}

@Component
public class KafkaConsumer implements Consumer<String> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

    private Map<String, SseEmitter> emitters = new HashMap<>();

    public SseEmitter register(String key) {
        LOG.debug("Registering sse client for {}", key);
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> emitters.remove(key));
        emitters.put(key, emitter);
        return emitter;
    }

    public void unregister(String key) {
        LOG.debug("Unregistering sse emitter for: {}", key);
        Optional.ofNullable(emitters.get(key)).ifPresent(SseEmitter::complete);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(String input) {
        LOG.debug("Got message from kafka stream: {}", input);
        emitters
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .forEach((SseEmitter emitter) -> {
                try {
                    emitter.send(event().data(input, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.debug("error sending sse message, {}", input);
                }
            });
    }
}

I am using StreamBridge, KafkaListener to send and listen message,
streamBridge.send("binding-import-device", device.getId());

@KafkaListener(topics = { "binding-import-device" }, groupId = "device")
    public void consume(String id) {
        log.info("consume device: {}", id);
    }

When I start my application, it prints these logs:
2024-11-29T00:07:51.560+07:00  WARN 21908 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-sound-device-3, groupId=device] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available. 
2024-11-29T00:07:51.560+07:00  WARN 21908 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-sound-device-3, groupId=device] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected 
2024-11-29T00:07:52.537+07:00  INFO 21908 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-sound-device-3, groupId=device] Node -1 disconnected. 

I am sending messages and consuming the messages in the same spring boot project, it always prints these logs and I can send the messages, but cannot consume these messages. I am dealing with this problem for weeks but it does not work out. I don't know where is "Bootstrap broker localhost:9092" which is printed in the logs. I am new to Kafka. Can you tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you so much.
I run Kafka with docker on 10.0.100.10
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.2.1
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.1
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:19092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafkatest:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui
    container_name: kafka-ui
    ports:
      - "8777:8080"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:19092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=zookeeper:2181


Where / how are you running Kafka?

@OneCricketeer I just updated my question, I am running Kafka with docker on 10.0.100.10

IP addresses don't really matter, and you should never use them with Docker networking... Where did you get your compose file? https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/docker/examples#examples

oh thank you, I found a way to address the problem
